# how to check input text using ActionScript 3 with movie clip button?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, button

im just working on my new project. All what i need is,
i want to check input text using button, if the value on the input text box is equals 1,
trace("true"), else trace ("false").

here's the example link http://localhostr.com/file/P2Q3bpn/test.fla

the problem is, when im trying to input text to 1, it's always goes to else, which means false. also all number. sorry for my bad english. here's what i did

```
var check:Boolean = false;
var input1:String;
var answer:String = "1";

MCButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, checkClick);

function checkClick(event:MouseEvent):void{
    input1= inputBox.text;
    check = true;
    if(input1 == answer){
        trace("true");
    }
    else trace("false");
}
```

thanks

Comment: What does trace(inputBox.text) show when you put '1' in the box?

Comment: it show 1. same as input

Comment: If your answers will always be numbers, try this: if(parseInt(input1) == parseInt(answer)) { ...

Comment: No problem :) Posted as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your answers will always be numbers, try this:

```
 if(parseInt(input1) == parseInt(answer))
 { 
    ...
    ...
    ...
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually you got "multiline" turned on. So what you are getting is "1\n" where "\n" is "new line". Which is not equal to "1". Turn off multiline and it will be ok.